# PHP getting data from HTML fields

Tags: mysql, php, html

I'm having some problems with getting data from HTML fields. This is how it looks in HTML

```
<form action="getInfo.php">
    <span>Series</span>
    <input class="searchFieldAlign" type="text" name="seriesName" /><Br>

    <span>Volume</span>
    <input class="searchFieldAlign" type="text" name="volumeName" /><Br>

    <span>Nr</span>
    <input class="searchFieldALign" type="text" name="issueNR" /><Br>

    <p input class="searchFieldALign" type=submit></p>
</form>
```

This is my php script:

```
<?php
$seriesName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['seriesName']);
$volumeName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['volumeName']);
$issueNR = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['issueNR']);
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","psswd","db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$qryIssueInfo = mysqli_query($con,"select issueNR, issueVolume, issueName, issueImageURL from issue, series where (seriesName='$seriesName') and (issueVolume='$volumeName') and (issueNR=$issueNR)");
$rowIssueInfo = mysqli_fetch_array($qryIssueInfo);
```

The problem is I don't get output from my query. There are no problems if i change it to this:

```
$qryIssueInfo = mysqli_query($con,"select issueNR, issueVolume, issueName, issueImageURL from issue, series where seriesName='Buffy, the Vampire Slayer' and issueVolume= 'Season 8' and issueNR=1");
```

Comment: Be careful with user input, or you'll end up like [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Can you please post the results of var_dump($volumeName).

Comment: For `mysqli_real_escape_string` you use a connection named `$conn` but you create your connection a few lines later with the name `$con`. So...whats `$conn`?

Comment: Typo, should be con in all the code

Answer (score 1):

If you not set form method = "post" it will be "get" and you should $_GET.

To correct:

```
<form method="post" action"getInfo.php">
```

Take it easy

Answer (score 0):

The first version does not contain the apostrophes around the variables.

You should also consider security issues, like SQL injection.

Comment: Apostrophes make no difference

Comment: It does. Think about an example when the input contains a space char, like: `WHERE field='word1 word2'`. Without apostrophes, the syntax would be incorrect.

Comment: I mean I tried it but the output stays the same. I didn't mean that the apostrophe itself had no function